# Look up a dynamic JNDI name

Tags: java, tomcat7, jndi, web.xml

My application code receives the JNDI name to look up at runtime. Hence, the JNDI name may not be configured beforehand in `web.xml` or in the `@Resource` annotation. How may I lookup an Object in such a scenario? Application is running on Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use resource injection but have to use programmatic lookup

```
new InitialContext().lookup(dynamicName)
```